# Does the mongo shell and possibly various drivers support queries that aren't strict JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb

I'd be the last to be picky about things, but it seems that in my learning of MongoDB, I'm seeing queries, inserts, etc. that are not what I understand to be strict JSON.  I mean all keys should have quotes around them, as well as values that are not numeric.  Am I wrong with regard to JSON itself, or is MongoDB just not being so picky about using a JSON-like syntax?  That might be the key term here, "JSON-like" syntax.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't use JSON in the first place. It uses BSON, which is kinda similar to JSON from the outside, but supports more types and, more importantly, is binary, not text.

What this means is that in *no* language/driver are MongoDB queries JSON.

Most MongoDB drivers use the underlying language's dictionary (hash map) type to represent queries, e.g.:

```
# Python example
blah = collection.find({'foo': 'bar'})
```

Note that `{'foo': 'bar'}` is a Python dict, not a JSON string. The MongoDB driver (PyMongo in this case) takes that dict and serializes it to BSON before sending it to the database. Whatever the DB sends back will be BSON too -- the driver deserializes it and gives it back to you as native Python data structures.

The same thing will happen in every other language I've looked at MongoDB support for. JSON is *never* used.